# propert width css not correctly work IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have a code:

```
.cl_Label{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  padding-top:0.2em;
  text-align:right;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

it's work in chrome but, ie 11 a property width not work correctly. I try:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>

<link href="../css/only-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <![endif]-->
```

but the css file not load.

What should I do? Tnks

Comment: What is the element in question? Is it "block", "inline-block" or "inline"? What's happening or not happening that it doesn't "work correctly"? Can you make a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Nb - In addition to WebDevRon's correct comments about conditional comments not being supported from Internet Explorer 10 onwards, the comment you have added about is specifically to target versions "Less Than or Equal" (LTE) to Internet Explorer 8, so the stylesheet would not have been loaded even if these were still supported by Microsoft. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx for more on conditional comments if you plan on using these in future projects (with the caveat that only older versions of Internet Explorer still support them at all).

Answer (score 2):

Conditional Comments are no longer available for IE 11. MS has dropped conditional comments as of IE10. [You can check from here](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/)

Comment: This answers the second part of the question, but not the part about the width.

Comment: Yes, I know that. but as he do not specified the exact problem, that is why I just answered that.